# Google Sheets Query / Array

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to build a very simple inventory sheet. Apologies in advance, but I'm very new at this.

a) I'd like my inventory sheet to show stock for individual items, and for kits (BOMs)
b) I'd also like the array formula to update depending on an adjacent column value (i.e. if the row shows 'fulfilled' then the array should ignore it.

I have been able to modify an old post that I found here, but unfortunately the original document was modified. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/23230245?hl=en

1. Does anyone have access to that original doc? I know Matt King was involved.
2. Does anyone know of a beginner's guide to Google Sheets Query / Array formulas?

I know I'm speaking in gibberish, but believe me I'm fascinated with this and I'm a quick learner. Would also be interested in paid coaching if anyone's into that!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btnxxI00qI9njIUzudAZXh4G87TWcHoWtfPl4jBl7jM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: where in which sheet you want that arrayformula and how should the output of that arrayformula look like?

Comment: I think the spreadsheet is missing a tab which has a simple inventory of all items. The output should be a simple count.

Comment: @player0 would be happy to talk about a project if you can help.

Comment: I am free, tho still not sure what are you after. can you create a new sheet in your spreadsheet and show some sample how do you wish data to be outputed?

Comment: see formulas in row 1 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btnxxI00qI9njIUzudAZXh4G87TWcHoWtfPl4jBl7jM/edit#gid=1380663533

Comment: Ahh that's, very helpful. If you can see I added the Vendor emulating your formulas. That's great. So now the Inventory is linked to the BOM Import, which imports from separate sheets. I think I can bring those sheets as tabs in the main Inv sheet for starters.

Comment: My goal is to populate column I of the Inventory Sheet, from values in BOM Import total quantities, and decrease when values of Starter Kits Requested column D is set to Fulfilled @player0

Answer (score 2):

```
={"Units"; ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY({'BOM Import'!F2:I},
 "select Col1,sum(Col4) 
  where Col4 is not null
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col4)''"), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]

---

```
={"Total Stock on Hand"; ArrayFormula(IF("yes"=IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {'BOM Import'!F2:F, 'BOM Import'!E2:E}, 2, 0)), SORTN(SORT({'Kits Requested'!B2:B, 'Kits Requested'!A2:D}, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 3, 1), 5, 0)), 0, 
 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY({'BOM Import'!F2:J}, "select Col1,sum(Col5) where Col5 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col5)''"), 2, 0))))}
```

[image]